# R: Escaping Repetition

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to avoid repetition.

My code:

```
df_purged <- subset(df, 
  A1 < 1.5 * IQR(A1) | A1 > 1.5 * IQR(A1) &
  A4 < 1.5 * IQR(A4) | A4 > 1.5 * IQR(A4) &
  A5 < 1.5 * IQR(A5) | A5 > 1.5 * IQR(A5) &
  A8 < 1.5 * IQR(A8) | A8 > 1.5 * IQR(A8) &
  A10 < 1.5 * IQR(A10) | A10 > 1.5 * IQR(A10))
df_purged
```

What I have tried (not working can't implement `and` operators):

```
df_purgedd<- subset(df, for(col in c (A1,A4,A5,A8,A10)){[col] < 1.5 * IQR([col]) | A1 > 1.5 * IQR([col])})
df_purgedd
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can loop through the columns of interest and apply the function, then `Reduce` it to a single logical vector with `&`

```
# create a function based on the logic
f1 <- function(x) x < 1.5 * IQR(x) | x > 1. 5 * IQR(x)
# loop through the columns with lapply, apply the 'f1' 
# and Reduce it to single logical vector
nm1 <- paste0("A", c(1, 4, 5, 8, 10))
i1 <- Reduce(`&`, lapply(df[nm1], f1))
# subset the rows
out <- subset(df, i1)
```

---

Or another option after creating the function is to use `filter_at`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    filter_at(vars(nm1), all_vars(f1))
```

Comment: Perfectly working. Thank you for your response. However, could you explain what is going on at the alternative solution?

Comment: @Mimayuki  In the second solution, `all_vars` check whether the columns all satisfy the condition in each row and only if it keeps that row